# PHP variable in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Consider this simple example;

```
<?php $text = test; ?>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">

var test;

test = "<?php echo $text; ?>"

$(document).ready(function(){
alert(test);
});

</script>
```

This works fine. Creating the alert with the text from the php var. However, if I place;

```
<?php $text = test; ?>
```

below the script - it does not work. I've tried the defer function. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Are you trying to get the value of the JavaScript variable `test` in PHP?

Comment: but where do you want to put the php variable? if you put it before the alert or in the alert method then it should work...

Comment: Note that `<?php $text = test; ?>` is wrong in any case unless you have a constant `test`. You should set a proper string: `<?php $text = 'test'; ?>`. If you think you are referring to the JavaScript variable `test` if you put the line at the end, then you are wrong. See @Quentin's answer in this case.

Comment: The problem here is very clear, but in general, please do not ever write "it does not work". "It does not work" is completely meaningless, and consequently highly irritating.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is pass PHP variables to javascript. Since my javascript code is defined in the <head> and my PHP variables obviously come after this in my code - I thought there may have been a simple solution. Thanks for all replies/help

Comment: Good practice is to put all your PHP logic (all the definition of variables) at the top of the page. One step further would be to separate logic and output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you place

```
  <?php $text = "test"; ?>
```

below the JS code, the the variable $text is not defined yet, so you cannot echo it *earlier* (**edit**) in the script.

Comment: What do you mean `$text` isn't defined? That code defines it! (Well, it tries to do so, but since assigning `test` will error (unless you've defined a constant called `test` or something), it breaks). Actually, in retrospect, the whole question doesn't make a lot of sense as it claims things work even though they should error.

Comment: @Quentin: If there is no constant `test`, then PHP interprets it as string `'test'`. That's why it works if this line is put before `<?php echo $text; ?>` but obviously it would not `echo` anything if it was put after it (this is what the OP tried). It is only unclear what the OP really wants to do (your answer also makes sense, given the ambiguity of `test`). In any way, the downvote is unjustified (whoever did this).

Comment: Read the second half of his post.  He mentions moving the $test definition to BELOW the javascript.  So, when echo $test happens, $test is not defined.

Comment: Wow. PHP really has kept the very worst bits of Perl. Take my previous comments as being unaware of PHP's unquoted strings feature.

Comment: Maybe you should substitute *later in the script* with *earlier in the script*.

Comment: @Quentin: To be fair, you do get an E_NOTICE for it. It shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to assign a client-side variable to a server-side variable?

Due to my knowledge, server-side variables can **NOT** "interact" directly with client-sider variables without anything in between. This means `<?php $test = test; ?>` doesn't work properly since variables that are included in `<?php ?>` will be treated as server-side variables, and thus, your client-side variable `test` is either considered as

- an undefined constant, or
- a string without quotes `''`

Answer (score 0):

There are two computers involved, the web server (which processes php) and the user's browser (which processes javascript).  So no, you cannot transfer a javascript variable back to php without sending the value of that variable from the user's browser to the web server (normally done by posting a form or ajax).